# Django - How to write a custom permission mixin?

Tags: django, django-permissions

There's a view that gets a parameter.

```py
class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request, pk):
         # ...             ^^
```

To decide whether the user is allowed or not, that parameter is needed. Is it possible to write a custom permission mixin to take care of it?

Comment: Hello there! Can you please provide additional details about what you are trying to achieve?